# Replace custom tags with html using preg_replace_callback

Tags: html, regex, parsing

Am trying to do a replacement of customized tags with html tags in my website as follows:

```
[block-2] "Donec volutpat nibh sit amet libero ornare non laoreet arcu luctus. Donec id arcu quis mauris". [/block-2]
```

If the above [block] tag is encountered, it should be replaced by some html tags (using regexp), specifically:

```
  <blockquote class="tm-style2"><span>
 "Donec volutpat nibh sit amet libero ornare non laoreet arcu luctus. Donec id arcu quis mauris".
 </span></blockquote>
```

I have tried the following but is not working. Please help:

```
$article_text = preg_replace_callback(
"(\[block-([0-9]+)\](.+)\[\/block-([0-9]+)\])",
create_function('$p','return "<blockquote class=\"tm-style".$p[1]."\"><span>".$p[2]."</span></blockquote>";'), $article_text);
```

Comment: There is no need to create preg_replace_callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to use preg_replace_callback function, just `preg_replace` would be fine.

```
\[(block-([0-9]+))\](.+?)\[\/\1\]
```

Then replace the matched characters with

```
<blockquote class="tm-style\2"><span>\n\3\n</span></blockquote>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yD8vZ3/5)

```
$re = "~\\[(block-([0-9]+))\\](.+?)\\[\\/\\1\\]~m";
$str = "[block-2] \"Donec volutpat nibh sit amet libero ornare non laoreet arcu luctus. Donec id arcu quis mauris\". [/block-2]";
$subst = '<blockquote class="tm-style\2"><span>'."\n".'\3'."\n".'</span></blockquote>';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

**Output:**

```
<blockquote class="tm-style2"><span>
 "Donec volutpat nibh sit amet libero ornare non laoreet arcu luctus. Donec id arcu quis mauris". 
</span></blockquote>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Could you explain why?

Comment: i mean copying your code into a new php file gives nothing as  a result when executed!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape closing tag's backslash in your pattern `...[\/block...`.

So full pattern is `(\[block-([0-9]+)\](.+)\[\/block-([0-9]+)\])`

Comment: sorry i mistyped it. even with that escape its still not working.